# load different xml file into an array in php

Tags: php, xml

I'm not really that good at php/XML I got this far using google etc. but cant get any further. 
I use

```
<?php
  $counter=0; 
 foreach($proxml->test->children() as $test1) {
  $counter++;
  $name=$test1->Name ;
  $test[$counter]="http://url".$name."/test?xml=1" ;
  }
$xml=simplexml_load_file("$test[1]");
$xml1=simplexml_load_file("$test[2]");
$xml2=simplexml_load_file("$test[3]");
$xml3=simplexml_load_file("$test[4]");
$xml4=simplexml_load_file("$test[5]");
$xmls = array( $xml, $xml1, $xml2, $xml3, $xml4 );
echo $xmls ;
?>
```

Each test is a different URL that has XML information like a UNIX time-stamp.

I want to put all XML files into an array and then extract all the < Time-stamps > and sort it. Then output it with the other information that belongs to the time-stamp like the < name > etc.

It works for 1 URL but cant get it to work for multiply URLs together.

Comment: What's wrong with running a `foreach($test as $url){$xml=simplexml_load_file($url);}`?

Comment: i use 1 xml file  the $proxml to get the names and with that name i make new urls which are then also XML. Each XML is the same just different names. so i want to sort something from it and show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$counter=0; 
foreach($proxml->test->children() as $test1) {
    $counter++;
    $name=$test1->Name ;
    $test[ $counter ] = "http://url" . $name . "/test?xml=1";
}

foreach( $test as $url ) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file( $url );
        // will display the xml, you can read it and get required values
    echo $xml->asXML();
}
?>
```

Comment: that shows things like public 3 65.4 1399400601 1399442265. but i only want to show the time stamp but how can i use it. to show the other information that is linked to the time stamp?

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of one xml?

Comment: http://puu.sh/9g4xS/e89f74e2af.png here is a screenshot of part of it. This is the $test xml's

Comment: there are multiple `achievement` nodes, and hence multiple timestamps in each xml. Read on how to loop through an xml..it's quite easy..

Comment: i got only the timestamps now. that works  but how can i show what name belongs to each timestamp>